# JavaScript function sets value for field in IE, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

This line works fine in Internet Explorer:

```
var outHtml = "<div align='left'><a href=\"javascript:setSupplier('Dummy');\">" + imgArrowLeft + "&nbsp;Ich finde meinen Lieferanten nicht oder kenne diesen nicht</a></div>";
```

I can click on the text on the right side.

[image: Works]

But when I use Chrome or Microsoft Edge, it doesn't work, i.e. I can't click on the text on the right:

[image: Text]

The `setSupplier()` is a simple function that sets the value of a Nintex Form Field:

```
function setSupplier(value) {
    NWF$("#" + varSupplierPicker).val(value);
}
```

How can one solve this issue?

Comment: I can't see any input field in your code, where do you want set value?

Comment: I don't know `Nintex`, but maybe you trןed this:
`<a href=\"setSupplier('Dummy');\">` (remove `javascript`)

Comment: @ZivBen-Or Tried it out, but it doesn't work sorry

Comment: I suggest you open the developer tools and check the source code. Also, try to check whether it shows any error or warning message or not. It can be possible that the code for link get broken in other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `onclick` instead.

```js
var outHtml = "<div align='left'><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"setSupplier('Dummy'); return false;\">" + imgArrowLeft + "&nbsp;Ich finde meinen Lieferanten nicht oder kenne diesen nicht</a></div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty "old" code there... Maybe the new browsers have better validators

```js
const imgArrowLeft = "<=="

const outHtml = `
  <div style="align: left;">
    <span style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; color: blue;" onclick="setSupplier('Dummy')">
      ${imgArrowLeft} Ich finde meinen Lieferanten nicht oder kenne diesen nicht
    </span>
  </div>`

function setSupplier(x) {
  console.log(x)
}
  
document.querySelector("#here").innerHTML = outHtml
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

Since a-tags are made for hyperlinks, you should consider to use a different tag when you want to run javascript.